# Parse, two different user types

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse for a backend for Android...my app has two different user types (doctor/patient)...how can I indicate the role of each of these user types?

Thanks so much

Michael Cabus

Answer (score 1):

You can create channel called "doctor" and "patient". In your app just subscribe one of these channel. Or before  read this https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#roles
This quote like your question's answer.

```
  ParseObject wallPost = new ParseObject("WallPost");
    ParseACL postACL = new ParseACL();
    postACL.setRoleWriteAccess("Moderators", true);
    wallPost.setACL(postACL);
    wallPost.save();
```

Comment: In the initial role assignment I have: ParseACL roleACL = new ParseACL(); ParseRole role = new ParseRole("Patient", roleACL); role.saveInBackground(); role.getUsers().add(newUser); Is this correct? I'm trying to see the role assignment in Parse but do not see it..thanks so much..